# Замена стандартного WebBrowser C#

Tags: c#

Как я понял, стандартный элемент WebBrowser базируется на IE 7.0. Некорректно отображается нужный мне сайт. Можно ли обновить его хотя бы до 11 версии? Или существуют ли сторонние библиотеки/фреймворки как альтернатива?

Comment: Думаю, он базируется на текущем системном IE. Обновите IE у клиента.

Comment: [статья по теме](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2015/01/12/controlling-webbrowser-control-compatibility.aspx)

Comment: А дописать `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` на сайте никак не судьба?

Comment: @VladD для интранет сайтов IE=edge даже в обычном IE не пробивает настройки совместимости - только указание конкретной версии кое-как работает. а WebBrowser скорее всего не пробивается вообще ничем - секьюрити, чтоб его

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WebBrowser базируется на текущем IE, но он принудительно запускается в режиме совместимости с IE7.

Решение - перед инициализацией контрола вписать в реестр по пути `Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\myapp.exe` ключ `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` со значением, соответствующим нужной версии браузера. Полный код для приведения WebBrowser в нормальный рабочий вид выглядит так:

```cs
private void SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(string feature, string appName, uint value)
{
    using (var key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(
        String.Concat(@"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\", feature),
        RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree))
    {
        key.SetValue(appName, (UInt32)value, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
    }
}

private void SetBrowserFeatureControl()
{
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330720(v=vs.85).aspx

    // FeatureControl settings are per-process
    var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);

    // make the control is not running inside Visual Studio Designer
    if (String.Compare(fileName, "devenv.exe", true) == 0 || String.Compare(fileName, "XDesProc.exe", true) == 0)
        return;

    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", fileName, GetBrowserEmulationMode()); // Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE10 Standards mode.
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_AJAX_CONNECTIONEVENTS", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_ENABLE_CLIPCHILDREN_OPTIMIZATION", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_MANAGE_SCRIPT_CIRCULAR_REFS", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_DOMSTORAGE ", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_GPU_RENDERING ", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_IVIEWOBJECTDRAW_DMLT9_WITH_GDI  ", fileName, 0);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_DISABLE_LEGACY_COMPRESSION", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN", fileName, 0);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_BLOCK_LMZ_OBJECT", fileName, 0);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_BLOCK_LMZ_SCRIPT", fileName, 0);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_DISABLE_NAVIGATION_SOUNDS", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_SCRIPTURL_MITIGATION", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_SPELLCHECKING", fileName, 0);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_STATUS_BAR_THROTTLING", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_TABBED_BROWSING", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_VALIDATE_NAVIGATE_URL", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_WEBOC_DOCUMENT_ZOOM", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_WEBOC_POPUPMANAGEMENT", fileName, 0);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_WEBOC_MOVESIZECHILD", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_ADDON_MANAGEMENT", fileName, 0);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_WEBSOCKET", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_WINDOW_RESTRICTIONS ", fileName, 0);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_XMLHTTP", fileName, 1);
}

private UInt32 GetBrowserEmulationMode()
{
    int browserVersion = 7;
    using (var ieKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer",
        RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree,
        System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryRights.QueryValues))
    {
        var version = ieKey.GetValue("svcVersion");
        if (null == version)
        {
            version = ieKey.GetValue("Version");
            if (null == version)
                throw new ApplicationException("Microsoft Internet Explorer is required!");
        }
        int.TryParse(version.ToString().Split('.')[0], out browserVersion);
    }

    UInt32 mode = 11000; // Internet Explorer 11. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE11 Standards mode. Default value for Internet Explorer 11.
    switch (browserVersion)
    {
        case 7:
            mode = 7000; // Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE7 Standards mode. Default value for applications hosting the WebBrowser Control.
            break;
        case 8:
            mode = 8000; // Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE8 mode. Default value for Internet Explorer 8
            break;
        case 9:
            mode = 9000; // Internet Explorer 9. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE9 mode. Default value for Internet Explorer 9.
            break;
        case 10:
            mode = 10000; // Internet Explorer 10. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE10 mode. Default value for Internet Explorer 10.
            break;
        default:
            // use IE11 mode by default
            break;
    }

    return mode;
}

public Form1()
{
    // до создания контрола
    SetBrowserFeatureControl();

    InitializeComponent();

    webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("https://www.whatismybrowser.com/");
}
```

код взят с [enSO: C# webbrowser Ajax call.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18333982/1988244)

Answer (score 0):

Так как в вопросе спрашивается про альтернативы, то предлагаю использовать основанный на Chromium [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp). Он существует как и элемент управления для Windows Forms, так и WPF. При этом включив его в проект он работает как отдельный браузер, а не является средством управления уже установленным браузером, поэтому вы не зависите от установленных версий браузера на машине клиента.